# Django ecommerce view that allows add_cart with same product_id but different product_options

Tags: django, django-views

I am writing a django ecommerce app that has multiple product options that can be optionally added to the same productid. I am having issues getting the view to recognize the same product with differing product options as separate cart items. I am getting it to work about half the time but only if a productid comes through with no options at all first then a follow on item with added options isnt an issue. If you attempt to add a bare product with no options into the cart with an existing same product id with options it either throws an error code or adds the options to the existing cart item and increments it up

### views.py

```
def add_cart(request, product_id, quantity=1):
  product = Product.objects.get(id = product_id) # get the product  
  product_options= request.POST.getlist('option')#gets selected product options   
  
  #
  try:
    cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request)) # get the cart using the cart_id present in the session
  except Cart.DoesNotExist:
    cart = Cart.objects.create(
        cart_id = _cart_id(request)
    )
  cart.save()#saves new cart if needed to be created   
  try:
    cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request)) # get the cart using the cart_id present in the session
  except Cart.DoesNotExist:
    cart = Cart.objects.create(
        cart_id = _cart_id(request)
    )
  cart.save()#saves new cart if needed to be created 
  
  try: 
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product = product, cart = cart)
    # if the product has multiple options, check if any of the options in the cart item matches the selected options 
    if len(product_options) > 0:
      match = False
      for option in cart_item.options.all():
        if option in product_options:
          match = True
          cart_item.quantity += quantity
          cart_item.save()
      # if none of the cart item options matches the selected options, add new cart item with selected options 
      if not match:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
          product = product,
          cart = cart,
          quantity = quantity,
        )
        if len(product_options) > 0:
          for item in product_options:
            cart_item.options.add(item)
        cart_item.save() 
    else:
      cart_item.quantity += quantity # adds the specified quantity of a single instance of product cart item
      cart_item.save()  
  except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
      product = product,
      cart = cart,
      quantity = quantity
    )
    if len(product_options) > 0:
      for item in product_options:
        cart_item.options.add(item)
    cart_item.save() 
  return redirect("cart")
```

i think that the main issue is that the view is initially looking for the matching option to be present regardless of follow on options when it is deciding to create a new instance. I need all of the options to be present and have the view increment +=1 or to create a new cart_item instance.

Im not sure how to loop through it effectively, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I understood what you were trying to refine codes about:

1. Cart case: "Get if exist, else create a new one."
2. CartItem case: "Add more quantity if exist, ortherwise, create a new one."

I think we could use [get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) in these cases.

These codes are my some ideas merely, you could tell me more what's your opinion, then I will try to help =)

```
from django.db.models import F


def add_cart(request, product_id, quantity=1):
    product = Product.objects.get(id = product_id) # get the product  
    product_options= request.POST.getlist('option') # gets selected product options 
    # get the cart using the cart_id present in the session
    cart, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(cart_id=_cart_id(request))

    # if the product has multiple options, check if any of the options in the cart item matches the selected options
    cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(
        product=product, cart=cart,
        defaults={
            'product': product,
            'cart': cart,
            'quantity': quantity
        }
    )
    for option in cart_item.options.all():
        if option in product_options:
            cart_item.quantity += quantity
        else:
            cart_item.options.add(item)
        cart_item.save()
    return redirect("cart")
```